# hive: dedupe data based on multiple conditions

Tags: hive, hiveql

Here is my sample data table

```
row#    date        customerid                      event       itemid-A     Itemid-B
1       5/1/17  4c9b3705121ac1493640912601          page load   473685  
2       5/1/17  11dacfc4251da01493672636536         page load   863438  
3       5/1/17  11dacfc4251da01493672636536         click       863438       45485
```

Condition#1: I need to remove row#2 form the data, since its a duplicate customer id with row #3. Basically remove page load events and keep click event when customerid is duplicate. Click event will have a unique Itemid-B

Condition#2: I need to keep page load event in row#1 when there is no duplicate customerid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  dt,customerid,event,itemid_A,Itemid_B

from   (select  * 
               ,row_number() over
                (
                    partition by    customerid
                    order by        field(event,'click','page load')
                ) as rn

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   rn = 1
;
```

---

```
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     dt     |         customerid          |   event   | itemid_a | itemid_b |
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 2017-05-01 | 11dacfc4251da01493672636536 | click     | 863,438  | 45,485   |
| 2017-05-01 | 4c9b3705121ac1493640912601  | page load | 473,685  | (null)   |
+------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```